# How to understand this execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I have a very complex execution plan and below is part of it, opened in Plan Explorer.
[image]
The image is kind of faded, I guess it's because all operators produce 0 rows.

As you can see, the arrow 1 is a clustered index seek, which produces 0 record. Why the the hash match operator (arrow 3) still has 53% cost? As I understand, hash match builds the hash table based on the output of the upper operator (which is 0 row in this case). After that it get all rows from the lower operator (arrow 2) and probes in the hash table. But in this case, they are all 0 rows. Why it still has such a high cost 53.4%?

Comment: Costs are pre-execution estimates. Stop looking at them. They’re mostly useless.

Comment: @ErikDarling Then where should I start finding the most consuming operator to tune?

Comment: You should run the query and get the actual execution plan and focus on operators that consume the most time.

Comment: @ErikDarling In my case the query is so slow and it never completes. The execution plan was pulled from the sp_whoisactive stored procedure and it includes actual number of rows etc, although they are all 0. See the image: https://i.imgur.com/GyloV0g.png

Comment: Relevant blog posts are standing by: [What To Do When Your Query Runs For Too Long To Get An Actual Execution Plan](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/what-to-do-when-your-query-runs-for-too-long-to-get-an-actual-execution-plan/)

Comment: Greyed out means that the operator wasn't even executed. If this is a live query plan then maybe it hadn't even got to that part of the plan yet as another part was taking a long time to execute

Comment: Please share the full query plan viaa https://pastetheplan.com, and please show us your full query, as well as relevant tables and indexes. Otherwise this question is not answerable.